# Update TextView from ListView android row

Tags: android, android-listview

I am retrieving some data in an Async class called from a Custom ArrayAdapter. When i add a new comment, i update the comment text view and that works ok, but after i reload the entire list the updates don't appear anymore. I can see in the logcat that there is a new comment nr, but not on the UI.

Shouldn't this : `answersListView.invalidateViews` be enough? I am trying to update that single row from the listview, to escape the issue with not updating the comment nr after a while.

```
private void updateView(int index) {
        System.out.println("index: " + index);
        View v = answersListView.getChildAt(index - answersListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

        if (v == null)
            return;

        final TextView nrComments = (TextView) v.findViewById(com.dub.mobile.R.id.showCommentsTxt);
        if (nrComments != null) {
            if (nrComments.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                // first comment
                nrComments.setText("1 comments");
            } else {
                // comments exist already
                int newNr = Integer.parseInt(nrComments.getText().toString().trim()
                        .substring(0, nrComments.getText().toString().trim().indexOf("comments")).trim()) + 1;
                nrComments.setText(newNr + " comments");
            }
            System.out.println("final nr of comments: " + nrComments.getText());
            nrComments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        answersListView.getAdapter().getView(position, v, answersListView);
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        answersListView.invalidateViews();
    }
```

And :

```
updateView(position);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: did you use notifyDataSetChanged() after updating the adapter of listview?

Comment: you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` before `updateView(position)`

Comment: You are changing the view data not the object data. So when yo call notifyDataSetChanged() your update will be lost. You need to update the Object in adapter and not the View

Comment: I was facing the problem of updating the TextView but your question solved my problem. Thanks for posting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty much what @Rami said in a comment to your question. You don't update directly the views, you just need to update the data. In your adapter, you override the getView method, in there is where you make all this changes, you don't need the updateViews method. 
Let me try to explain how it works.

1. The listView uses an Adapter.
2. The List view ask the Adapter "give me the view in X position" with the getView method.
3. The adapter creates that view, is returned to the ListView, and that what is shown.
4. The Adapter itself, should contain a List with the data you want to show.
5. Those views (rows) are created and destroyed everytime one of those views become visible or invisible in the screen, or if you call the notifyDataSetChanged method.

   So now, the thing is, if you change, let's say, the object in the position 5, of the adapter List for a different object with new data, then next time the ListView ask the Adapter to give me the view in the position 5, the adapter is going to create the View (row) with the new data. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to update the data in the UI thread.
if you have context in your Async class use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //update here
            }
        });
```

or

```
android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //update here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you change data for an item in a list view. You must have used some array of strings to fill data in textview in the getView function of the adapter. You only need to change that array and then call notifydatasetchanged on adapter. Views are recycled by adapter so above does not make sense

getView (...)
{
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setText(myData[index]); // You need to change myData array contents
}

Comment: The custom adapter extends ArrayAdapter but uses a custom object not just a simple string. I am using data from the object to update some elements from the listview row. What you said above is correct, i am using that in the adapter.

Comment: Yes, please only change the custom object contents, and call notifydatasetchagned. let me know if it works